# Use code behind in CSS

Tags: css, asp.net

I would like to define a `background-color` of an element by using a value stored in a `resource (resx)` file. I'm willing to write that specific part of the `CSS` in the `aspx` page instead of in an external CSS file.

I tried using both the `<%= %>` notation, and the  `<%# %>` notation. However, neithr of them work:

**When I try using `<%= %>`:**

```
.lblHolisticStatus{
    background-color: <%= Resources.ItemList.NeedsSupportColor %> ;
}
```

I get an error:

```
The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).
```

**And when I try using `<%# %>`:**

```
.lblHolisticStatus{
    background-color: <%# Resources.ItemList.NeedsSupportColor %> ;
}
```

I don't get an error, but no value either. This is how I see it in the view source of the page:

```
.lblHolisticStatus{
    background-color:  ;
}
```

Solutions I would rather not do:

- I don't want to define the `background-color` in the code behind, because I like to have the `CSS` definitions done in CSS, so maintenance is easier.
- Assigning a different css class to element containing background color wouldn't help, because I would still have to define the background-color in CSS. And I would still want to use a value from the Resource file...

This is my full code (minus non-relevant elements):

```
<head runat="server">
    <style>
        .lblHolisticStatus{
            float:left;
            font-size:1.7rem;
            color:#fff;
            padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
            background-color: <%# Resources.ItemList.NeedsSupportColor %> ;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="categoryStatus cf">
        <span class="lblHolisticCategory">
            <%=CategoryName ?? Resources.ItemList.DataNotFound %>
        </span>
        <span class="lblHolisticStatus cls<%= ((eStatus)Type).ToString()%>">
            <%=GetGlobalResourceObject("ItemList", char.ToUpper(((eStatus)Type).ToString()[0]) + ((eStatus)Type).ToString().Substring(1))%>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why can't you assign different css class to element containing background color? You would need two classes created in that case and give different one each time based on you needs.

Comment: That wouldn't help, because I would still have to define the background-color in CSS. And I would still want to use a value from the Resource file...

Comment: The first scenario's error (`The Controls collection...`) is odd, can you provide more context?

Comment: Have you tried to put a `DataBind()` in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`? That's necessary if you use `<%# `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can't use `<% %>` inside `<head>` when running at the server (`<head runat="server">`). ([here's another reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357138/)).
What you can do is either run at the client, or move the `<style>` part down into the `<body>`.

Comment: Thanks, Amit. Your answer set me in the right direction: you can't use `<%= %>` inside `<head>`, *when `<head>` has attribute `runat="server"`* (sorry, It slipped from the full code I added). Once I removed `runat="server"` (it actually wasn't needed), I could use `<%= %>`, and then no need for `this.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround :

use : (with `#`)

```
 background-color: <%# Resources.ItemList.NeedsSupportColor %> ;
```

and do in page_load :

`this.DataBind()`

*But I must say you're doing something wrong there. (show us the full code)*

Comment: Thanks! I would love to understand what I'm doing wrong. Added full(er) code to question